# placing $.mobile.changePage in the right place

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to understand how $.mobile.changePage works. I placed the method $.mobile.changePage in an anonymous function after the last element in the DOM and it didnt work but if I was to place it in document.ready it works fine. How come? any advice much appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="foo">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Foo</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
            <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

    <!-- Start of second page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="bar">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Bar</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">   
            <p>I'm the second in the source order so I'm hidden when the page loads. I'm just shown if a link that references my id is beeing clicked.</p>      
            <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

    <script>
        (function(){ 

                $.mobile.changePage($("#bar"), { transition: "slideup"} );          

        })();// this doesn't work


        $(document).ready(function(){

                $.mobile.changePage($("#bar"), { transition: "slideup"} );

            })//this works

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`document ready`** dont work correctly with **`jQuery Mobile`**. Usually it will trigger before pages are loaded inside the **`DOM`**.

If you want to find more about this take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

To make it work you need to use correct page event, like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#foo', function(){       
    $.mobile.changePage($("#bar"), { transition: "slideup"} );
});
```

At the same time this is not a good solution. You should not change page while first page is loading, mainly because it will cause **`jQuery Mobile`** to misbehave. Ether do it after first page is successfully loaded (page **`#foo`**) or change page order and let page **`#bar`** be the first page.